# Solve the functional equation $z\cdot f(z)= \frac{z-2}{2} +(z-3)\cdot f(z-1).$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, functional-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a function of the complex variable $z$, satisfying the functional equation:
$$\tag{1} z\cdot f(z)= \frac{z-2}{2} +(z-3)\cdot f(z-1).$$
It is easy to verify that $g(z)=\frac{3z-5}{24}$ is a solution to (1).

Are there other solutions?

More precisely, what condition -the least restrictive the better- on $f$ would be needed for $g$ be the only solution to (1)?

Comment: There are multiple functions in the reals: Wolfram Alpha gives $\frac{6c_1}{(z^2-3z+2)z} + \frac{3z-5}{24}$ as the general solution for real functions, with $c_1$ being an arbitrary parameter. You would therefore need $f$ to be a real, linear function to force $g$ to have a unique solution.

Comment: @Toby Mak  thanks for the comment.  Do you mean that it suffices that $f$ be defined over the whole complex plane, for $\frac{3z-5}{24}$ to be the unique solution?

Comment: No, it suffices that $f$ be defined over the reals only.

Comment: @Toby Mak  If you know of a proof, would you mind write it as an answer?

Comment: Basically you should solve the recurrence relation to prove it for the integers. I have no idea how to prove it or if it holds for the real numbers as well, but this is probably where to start.